# How to create sub string in a line read from text file separated by comma

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, file-handling

I am java script newbie and i have a text file like this Address.txt :

```
Andhra Pradesh,East Godavari,Reach within 36 Hrs
Andhra Pradesh,Guntur,Reach within 36 Hrs
Andhra Pradesh,Krishna,Reach within 36 Hrs
Andhra Pradesh,Visakhapatnam,Reach within 36 Hrs
Andhra Pradesh,Chittoor,Reach within 36 Hrs
```

Now i want to separate each loine by substring by comma , hence there will be 3 sub strings. Which must be stored in three arrays.

How to do that in Javascript lets say my way reading this file is :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Address.txt',
            dataType: 'text',
        }).success(function (test)
        {
              alert('inside ajax : '+test);//lets say this show aall the data of test file
            var col1 = [];
            var col2 = [];
           var col3 = [];
            var j = 0;
                //How to concert them in substring and save in these tree columns ?
            for (var i = 0; i <= test.length - 3; i = i + 3) 
            {

            }     

        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split()`

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

So first we need to split on the newline `\n` character to get all of the lines. Then for each line, we split on the comma `,` character to get each of the three substrings, as you say.

Here is a verbose but simple way to do it:

```
var lines = test.split('\n');
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var cols = lines[i].split(',');
    col1.push(cols[0]);
    col2.push(cols[1]);
    col3.push(cols[2]);
}
```

So for every line, we add the first substring to the `col1` array, the second to the `col2` array, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
var array = string.split(',');
```

**split** function will split the string based on the **comma** and you will get the array in the `var array`.

Use the above logic for each of the three strings you have mentioned and store it in the **cols** as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this google script to convert any CSV file into array or objects

http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/examples/basic-usage.html